# Create a table based on filtering dataframe on progressive criteria with two variables in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have the following dataframe with the following variables
age (continuous), risk (continuous), disease (0/1).

e.g;

```
age <- c(45, 50, 55, 60, 65);

risk <- c(5, 45, 70, 80, 50);

disease <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
```

I would like to create a table whereby the columns subset data by one variable (age > 40, age > 45, age > 50) and rows by another (risk > 20, risk > 25, etc.) and the table populated by counts/summary statistics for those observatios that meet the criteria for both column and row variable.

I was going to calculate each value using `dplyr`, e.g.,

```
a <- df %>% 
filter(age>40, risk >20) %>%
summarise(prop.dis = sum(disease)/n())
```

But is there a shorter way to auto-populate a whole table with columns subsetting data by an incremental criteria and rows the same?

Answer (score 0):

If we need to get the proportion for each corresponding filter, use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
agevec <- c(40, 45, 50)
riskvec <- c(20, 25, 30)
map2(agevec, riskvec, ~ df %>% 
                filter(age > .x, risk > .y) %>%
                summarise(prop.dis = sum(disease)/n()))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, however, i only get one list - not multiple lists?